# Как можно вернуть свойство объекта (элемент массива) по значению из другого массива? JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 2 массива, один с idшниками, в другом объекты с айдишником и именем которое предназначено для этого айдишника:

```
const arr1 = [11, 15, 33];
const arr2 = [{id: 11, name: 'name11'}, {id: 15, name: 'name15'}, {id: 33, name: 'name33'}];
```

Как вернуть массив с именами из arr2, по айдишникам из arr1?

Мой вариант (рабочий):

```
 const result = arr2.filter((el) => arr1.find((id) => id === el.id)).map((el) => el.name);
```

Возможно это можно сделать с меншим числом итераций, мне кажеться это не очень хороший вариант с точки зрения оптимизации (если будет много елементов в массивах) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш алгоритм хорош, в принципе - `O(nm)`. Можно сделать в `O(n + m)`. Чуть больше памяти в процессе выполнения займет, зато сложность линейная.

```
const keys = {};
arr1.forEach(key => keys[key] = null);
const result = arr2.reduce((names, obj) => {
    if (obj.id in keys) {
        names.push(obj.name);
    }
    return names;
}, []);
```

Comment: вот еще немного упрощенный вариант arr1.map(id => arr2.find(item => item.id === id).name)

Comment: неверно, у вас на первом же `undefined` из `find` упадет скрипт

Comment: '?.' думаю решит эту проблему

Comment: ок, решит ошибку. а с `undefined` в результате что делать будем?

Comment: К тому же вы все равно итерируете массив внутри другого итератора. То есть вы умножаете количество повторений. При длинах `arr1.length = 5, arr2.length = 4` вы получите `20` обходов. Вместо `9` в варианте с прямым доступам по ключам.

Comment: да, нужна будет дополнительная проверка

Answer (score 0):

Можно так например:

```js
const arr1 = [11, 15, 33];
const arr2 = [{id: 11, name: 'name11'}, {id: 15, name: 'name15'}, {id: 33, name: 'name33'}];

const result = arr2.flatMap(item => (arr1.includes(item.id) ? [item.name] : []))
console.log(result)
```